# How to return all "Data" matching query parameters specified in route

Tags: node.js, query-string

I'm quite new to nodejs. I recently dived into REST API endpoints using basic data structure. I am making a `GET/loans` which normally returns all my loan applications. But I'm trying to refactor it to cater for the query parameters endpoint `GET/loans?status=approve&repaid=true` && `GET/loans?status=approve&repaid=false`

This is what my get request looks like. which is working perfectly

```
static getLoans(req, res) {
    return res.status(200).send({
      status: 200,
      data: loans,
    });
  }
```

I am trying to refactor it to return loans whose details matches the query parameters, which isnt working:

```
static getLoans(req, res) {
    if (req.query) {
      const queryStatus = req.query.status;
      const queryRepaid = req.query.repaid;
      const data = loans.filter(item => item.queryStatus && queryRepaid);
      return res.status(200).send({
        status: 200,
        data,
      });
    }
    return res.status(200).send({
      status: 200,
      data: loans,
    });
  }
```

How do I go about it? Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const data = loans.filter(item => item.queryStatus === queryStatus && item.queryRepaid === queryRepaid);
```

However, you could query the results from database like so:

```
return Loans.find({queryStatus: queryStatus, queryRepaid: queryRepaid});
```